# Why Couchbase document size is just 2.5KB?

Tags: couchbase

The default documents size allowed is just 2.5KB what is the reason for that? I found answer how to increase it, are normally documents are less than 2.5KB?

Comment: Where did you find that? Official [docs](http://www.couchbase.com/docs/couchbase-manual-2.0/couchbase-server-limits.html) say that limit is 20 Mbytes.

Comment: yes that's true, but when I create document and then edit it, it return this error. Here is exact message:
"Warning: Editing of document with size more than 2.5kb is not allowed (Invalid document)"

Comment: It's only limitation for couchbase admin's web gui. You can use rest api or client library, if you want to view/edit large docs.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

2.5 KB size limit is only for web console based CRUD operations and not for rest based CRUD operations

To increase the size limit open the document

```
/opt/couchbase/lib/ns_server/erlang/lib/ns_server/priv/public/js/documents.js
```

search for `docBytesLimit` in the document, its value will be `2500`, change it to the value you want.

Comment: On OSX, the file is located at `/Applications/Couchbase\ Server.app/Contents/Resources/couchbase-core/lib/ns_server/erlang/lib/ns_server/‌​priv/public/js/documents.js`

Comment: very restrictive for dev who dont have access to the js file (ie shared hosting, server managed by someone else..) I hope Couchbase team will increase it in next releases, to at least 32ko , or at least give a read only view of the document to see the content.

Comment: Yeah, it's a VERY small limit, it's so annoying :(